# How to extract Correlation of Coefficients table from models like glm?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, glm, lm

After running a statistical model in R (e.g., `glm`, `lm`, `lme4::lmer`, etc.), I run the `summary()` command with `corr=TRUE` to get the Correlation of Coefficients table. It features a matrix of correlations for the intercept and the independent variables in the given model. What I would like to do is extract the columns that make those correlations possible. For instance, if the model is `x ~ a + b`, and the table looks like this...

```
 (Intercept)   a   
a    0.##      
b    0.##     0.##
```

I want to extract the columns that allow for the correlation between `a` and `b`.

I have found various commands to extract fitted values and residuals, but nothing to yet that would give me values for `a` and `b` that correspond to their correlations in that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the `summary(.)$correlation`.

If you want to extract something from an `object`, look into the structure `str(object)` to find the desired element. (If you are working in RStudio, perhaps start with `str(object, max.levels=1)` as it tends to hang up or crash if the output is too large.)

Looking into the source code of `fitted()` methods such as `stats:::fitted.lm` reveals, that they essentially extract the `$fitted.values` element of the respective object (similar applies to `resid()`).

Same way we could write a function `ex_corr_lm()`. To obtain the RHS variables automatically we may use `all.vars()` on the formula element.

The `object` also contains the `model` data which is the part of data from the original data used to fit the model. If there were `NA`s, they might be removed. We can use it to reconstruct the columns that "make those correlations possible".

```
> ex_corr_lm <- \(object, data=FALSE, vars) {
+   if (missing(vars)) {
+     vars <- all.vars(s$call$formula)[-1]
+   } 
+   if (inherits(object, c("lm", "glm"))) {
+     s <- summary(object, corr=TRUE)
+     corr <- s$correlation[vars, vars]
+     corr_data <- object$model[, vars]
+   } else if (inherits(object, "lmerMod")) {
+     s <- summary(object, corr=TRUE)
+     corr <- as.matrix(s$vcov@factors$correlation)[vars, vars]
+     corr_data <- object@frame[, vars]
+   } else {
+     stop('not implemented.')
+   }
+   if (data) {
+     list(corr=corr, corr_data=corr_data)
+   } else {
+     corr
+   }
+ }
```

```
> ex_corr_lm(f_lm)
           a          b
a  1.0000000 -0.4798395
b -0.4798395  1.0000000
> 
> ex_corr_lm(f_lm, vars=c('a', 'b'))  ## explicitly specify vars
           a          b
a  1.0000000 -0.4798395
b -0.4798395  1.0000000
> 
> ex_corr_lm(f_glm)
           a          b
a  1.0000000 -0.4798395
b -0.4798395  1.0000000
> 
> ex_corr_lm(f_lmer)
           a          b
a  1.0000000 -0.4798395
b -0.4798395  1.0000000
```

If we set `data=TRUE`, we can obtain the respective columns. `ex_corr_lm()` throws a list with correlations and data columns in this case.

```
> ex_corr_lm(f_lm, TRUE)
$corr
           a          b
a  1.0000000 -0.4798395
b -0.4798395  1.0000000

$corr_data
   a   b
1  1   1
2  2   4
3  3   9
4  4  16
5  5  25
6  1  36
7  2  49
8  3  64
9  4  81
10 5 100
```

We can use `cor()` on them. Note, that correlations of the estimated coefficients and the correlation between the variables themselves aren't necessarily the same.

```
> ex_corr_lm(f_lm, TRUE)$corr_data |> cor()
          a         b
a 1.0000000 0.4798395
b 0.4798395 1.0000000
```

---

*Data:*

```
> set.seed(42)
> d <- data.frame(a=rep(1:5, 2), b=(1:10)^2);d$x <- .5 + 2*d$a + .1*d$b + rnorm(10,,.5)
> f_lm <- lm(x ~ a + b, d,)
> f_glm <- glm(x ~ a + b, d, fam=gaussian())
> f_lmer <- lme4::lmer(x ~ a + b + (1|a), d)
```

Comment: Thanks for the instructive comment. It is not, however, what I am looking for. I'm looking for the columns that make the correlations from the table possible. For instance, if I look at str(object) as you suggested, which aspect parts of the object would I need to correlate in order to reproduce the correlation table?

Comment: @kneergaard We can move `summary` calculations into the function, since we need both, information from the fitted object and the summary. Please see updated answer.